# Which kind(or kinds) of GC algorithms does python actually use?

Tags: python, algorithm, garbage-collection

As we known, ****Reference Counter****, ****Mark-Sweep****, ****Mark-Copy**** are three GC algorithms using most widely in programming languages. I used to believe that Reference Counter is the only GC algorithm that python use. Recently, however, when I planned to learn further about Python's GC mechanism I came across an article titled ****Principle of Python garbage collector and its application****. The author talked about all of the three kinds of GC algorithms in his paper without pointing out which algorithm(or algorithms) does python actually use. Then I turned to the search engine as well as several domestic forums about python hoping to find a specific answer, failed. Results were even more confusing. **Until now,  I'm still unsure which kind of GC algorithms does python use?  If Reference Counter was actually used, how to solve the trouble of ****Circular Reference**** and ****Mutual Reference****?**

Comment: May be these articles will help: 1. [Visualizing Garbage Collection in Ruby and Python](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/10/24/visualizing-garbage-collection-in-ruby-and-python) 2. [Generational GC in Python and Ruby](http://patshaughnessy.net/2013/10/30/generational-gc-in-python-and-ruby)